# How sort a collection of associative arrays in PHP by a specific attribute

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array. I want sort this, how I can do that?

```
 array:2 [▼
      0 => Collection {#198 ▼
        #items: array:2 [▼

      0 => {#201 ▼

        +"id": 2;
        +"title": "Now eldest";
        +"description": "Now eldest new tastes plenty mother called misery get."
        +"created_at": "2017-07-07 16:34:00"
      }

      1 => {#197 ▼

        +"id": 6
        +"title": "dffd"
        +"description": "fdfdfdfdfdffdfdf"
        +"created_at": "2017-07-07 10:23:00"
      }]  }
      1 => Collection {#189 ▼
        #items: array:2 [▼

      0 => {#208 ▼

        +"id": 5
        +"title": "However, if you are not using Homestead"
        +"description": "The Laravel framework has a few system requirements."
        +"created_at": "2017-07-07 13:37:00"
      }

      1 => {#196 ▼

        +"id": 7
        +"title": "fedffdf"
        +"description": "fdfdfdf"
        +"created_at": "2017-07-07 09:12:00"
      }] }]
```

I work of an application, I want to show in timeline all posts sorted by time 'created_at'.
How can I do that?

Comment: Seems to be a Laravel collection, if so https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby

Comment: Always, if getting data from a database, do the sorting at that level and save yourself a lot of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `usort`:

```
usort($collection, function(array $a, array $b) {
    return $a["created_at"] <=> $b["created_at"];
});
```

If you are using a version of PHP that does not have the `<=>` operator, try this instead:

```
usort($collection, function(array $a, array $b) {
    return $a["created_at"] >= $b["created_at"] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Link to the documentation: [PHP: usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)